# What is this bug about Jacobi's iteration of python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is part of the code of the Jacobi iterative method for solving the system of linear equations, and the code problem is that the previous solution vector of the iteration is the same as the solution vector of this one.

```py
import numpy as np
def Jacobi(A,b,x,e,N): ## Ax=b,e precision ,N max times 
    A,b=np.array(A,dtype=float),np.array(b,dtype=float)
    n=A.shape[0]
    x,y=np.array(x),np.zeros(n)
    for k in range(N):
        for i in range(n):
            m=0
            for j in range(n):
                m=m+A[i,j]*x[j]
            y[i]=x[i]+(b[i]-m)/A[i,i]
        R=max(abs(x-y))
        x=y
        print(R)
A=[[5,-1,-1,-1],[-1,10,-1,-1],[-1,-1,5,-1],[-1,-1,-1,10]]
B=[-4,12,8,34]
x0=np.zeros(4)
Jacobi(A,B,x0,0.001,10)
```

x and y should be unequal, but the program output R=0.Just like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRyAK.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-debugging or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the line 13

```py
x=y.copy()
```

Because x=y make x=y forever.